# Draw google chart with changing amount of data series' on chart

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-visualization

First time poster, LONG time googler:

I am building a php web application in conjunction with mysql. I have no issues with retrieving data from the mysql database or populating google charts, but this time the chart I have in mind will select its data series from a changing number of items. Those items will determine mysql queries to actually populate the chart, but I need the data off the other table to determine the query first.

For instance: It could read the amount of sales for the years 2010, 2011, and 2012. But when the next year rolls in, it would also need to read data for 2013. I would like to do this automatically. I am not using years in my code, it is much more dynamic than that, data series could be removed from the table, or added to it.

I am curious if anyone has done this and can point me in the right direction for some code to learn. I have hunted around for this and come up with nothing that even gives me a hint on how to begin doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.  I built text files (via PHP) that represented the data I wanted to chart.  The charts pull the same text files each time, but of course the content of those files changes each time I run the PHP script.

Comment: That is sort of what Im saying, but what I am looking for is to be able to pull from different numbers of text files, say you have 3, the chart will have 3 series, but you make a 4th, the chart would automatically add the 4th. These 'text files' will be entries in a mysql database, so no issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if im a dummy or not, but a for loop with an embedded if statement got it done for me. Just took some time getting one thing to work at a time.
{
  function packageChart() {

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Location/Package', 'Item Count'],
      //determine number of packages for for loop

      <?php
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select count(package_id_number) from packages;");
                $stmt->execute();
                $totalPackageCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();

         //for loop to iterate through each package to count pipe
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPackageCount; $i++) {
             $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select package from packages where package_id_number = ?;");
             $stmt->execute([$i]);
             $selectedPackage = $stmt->fetchColumn();

             $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select count(item_id) from test_inventory where assigned_package = ? and date_cert > curdate() - interval 1 year;");
             $stmt->execute([$selectedPackage]);
             $indiPackageCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
             $packageCount = $indiPackageCount.$i;

             if($i < $totalPackageCount) {
                 echo '[\''.$selectedPackage.'\','.$packageCount.'],';
                 }

             else {
                 echo '[\''.$selectedPackage.'\','.$packageCount.']';
                  }
               }
      ?>
  ]);
```

}